# Location of Chrome cache on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser-cache

After a bit of Googling, I'm able to find the location of Chrome cached files on Windows but not on OS X. Would anyone know what the location is for Mac?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The primary cache is nominally `~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome`.
However the bulk of cached data appears in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`,
in particular `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Application Cache`.

If you are a Time Machine user, consider excluding the Application Support directories, as they bloat your backup set.  Take care to preserve the bookmarks file if that's important to you, as it's mixed into the same directory.

Comment: Has the cache moved in newer versions?  I can't find it in any of these places...

Comment: @Jeff: I'm using 12.0.742.77 beta and those directories still seem correct. Not sure about dev versions.

Comment: @Jeff, make sure that you're in your user Library folder and not the root directory's Library folder. I made that mistake when initially looking for it.

Comment: Note that ~/Library is normally hidden in finder.  Use Menu -> go and type in 'Library'

Comment: Or use menu -> hold down "option/alt" -> link to Library appears for you to click on.

Comment: On my machine, ~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome has far more data.  But thanks for both paths. +1

Comment: Yes, this worked. Here is a posting as well.
http://www.30isthenew20.com/technology/fix-missing-favicons-google-chrome/

Comment: How to change the location?

Answer (score 5):

And if you're using RockMelt build - `~/Library/Caches/RockMelt/Default`

Answer (score 1):

Open documents
Right click and select "Show library"
now you can find library in "documents"
then follow:
Library/Caches/Google/Chrome