# History Provider Cache File for Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have been having a sluggish omnibox, and one of the fixes people suggest is to delete the history provider cache file from the user directory, however I was not able to find this file on Chrome OS, if anyone knows where it is, I would appreciate knowing where I could delete it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

When I originally answered this I did it through my phone and had to hand type the path as I was trying to remove all sorts of malware from a friends Win7 PC.

I suspect that this is different on different platforms and you did not specify yours.

If you are on Windows I would try using CCleaner as it would make mady other recommendations.  [This post](http://internetlifeforum.com/chrome/1289-how-delete-google-chrome-omnibox-history-cache/) shows a likely path `\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

Did not find on MacOs, but [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/197786/location-of-chrome-cache-on-mac-os-x) may be of help

**Orig:**

CCleaner will list and remove
'.../Chrome/user data/default' is where I found it

Comment: CCleaner+chromium OS...Could you please provide the steps to find out cache over here. That will be a great help.