# Recover frozen active chrome downloads from RAM?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, memory, data-recovery, download

**TLDR:**

**How can I salvage downloads stuck in chrome RAM on MacOS?** The downloads folder was inaccessible at the time of download, so I'm hoping the files are still in ram or a temp file somewhere. I have not killed chrome since the downloads. I no longer have access to the files so I can't just redownload them.

[image: Chrome desktop icon with download balloon, with the number 5.]

**Context:** I am using Chrome 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (x86_64) on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 MBP.
My default download location is set to a folder in a network mounted drive I am connected to by ethernet. I disconnected from ethernet and used wifi while working in a different room, and tried to download some files / [Go Full Page](https://gofullpage.com/) web screenshots before remembering to change my downloads folder to a local folder. New downloads worked fine and I have since reconnected to my network drive and new downloads once again go to the proper network folder.

Unfortunately, my original downloads did not save. They seem to be stuck in some download purgatory as they are still shown active on the icon, ([image included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCTaM.png)) but do not appear in `chrome://downloads/`, `filesystem:chrome-extension://fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl/persistent/`, or my local or network downloads folders.

Comment: Under *nix (and BSD) there are several temp dir used to download chunks of files. The main one in `\tmp`. After there are others as your username under `\tmp\myusername`, `mozilla`... Another place where to give it a look is under your home. Hidden files (starting with a `.`, e.g. `.myHiddenDir` or `.myHiddenFile`). Then It should be the Chrome temp dir... So even if it is -in principle- possible that it still is in the RAM, it is not so probable. Ususally part of the files are with the `.part` suffix added.

Comment: Give it a look [here](https://superuser.com/a/197787/257269)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware, App Store) & see if you can find one of the names (search an obvious chunk of name, avoiding punctuation etc) in invisible/hidden/system areas. macOS & Safari/appstore/updates often use `/private/var/` for partial downloads. Chrome may not (some apps build a `name.download` type file directly in the destination folder, which you can't usually unpack until it's finished), but there's every chance it's buried well down inside something practically unsearchable by a human.

Make sure in settings you select 'scan all files', then 'invisible' in the search sidebar.

Example

[image]

Comment: EasyFind seems to be unavailable on the US App Store 

Comment: Hmmm… not on the UK store either now - but Google can find it on other repositories, I got it from CNet - https://download.cnet.com/EasyFind/3000-2248_4-8707.html